# google spreadsheet CSV import issues

Tags: csv, import, formatting, google-sheets

I struggling with a csv file that i need to import into google sheet.
This file is inserted everyday in a google spreadsheet, I need to be able to have a script or a working "split" function to be able to process it.

```
vie feb 19 15:12:58 ART 2016,
Reporte final de resultados
                    ,"             ","     Banca Inicial         "," ","            Fill           "," ","           Credits         "," ","        Banca Final        "," ","            Drop           "," ","           Win","              "," Porc.","   Match Play ","     Propinas "
 Juego              ," Mesa      ","      Colones ","    Dolares ","      Colones ","    Dolares ","      Colones ","    Dolares ","      Colones ","    Dolares ","      Colones ","    Dolares ","      Colones ","    Dolares "," Hold ","      Dolares ","      Colones "
Ruleta              ,"     1     ","     4,381,000","       7,538","              ","       6,000","              ","            ","     4,275,500","       8,729","     1,054,000","       3,758","       943,500","      -1,056"," 89.52","            20","         5,000"
                    ,"     2     ","     5,440,300","      14,217","              ","            ","              ","            ","     5,145,300","      14,427","       170,000","          40","      -125,000","         250","-73.53","              ","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","     9,821,300","      21,755","              ","       6,000","              ","            ","     9,420,800","      23,156","     1,224,000","       3,798","       818,500","        -806"," 66.87","            20","         5,000"
Punto y Banca       ,"    21     ","     2,596,000","      17,048","     7,000,000","      30,000","     4,700,000","      12,710","     3,276,000","      13,922","       450,000","      25,500","    -1,170,000","       5,084","-260.0","           525","              "
                    ,"    22     ","     4,766,500","      19,836","     5,400,000","      30,000","     3,800,000","      25,800","     3,526,500","      18,364","     1,920,000","      18,200","      -930,000","      12,528","-48.44","         1,250","        10,000"
                    ,"    23     ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","     7,362,500","      36,884","    12,400,000","      60,000","     8,500,000","      38,510","     6,802,500","      32,285","     2,370,000","      43,700","    -2,100,000","      17,612","-88.61","         1,775","        10,000"
RUM                 ,"    31     ","     3,852,500","       5,956","              ","            ","              ","            ","     3,852,500","       5,956","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
                    ,"    32     ","     5,814,200","       6,414","              ","            ","              ","            ","     5,814,200","       6,414","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
                    ,"    33     ","     5,354,000","      10,628","              ","            ","              ","            ","     5,354,000","      10,626","              ","       2,000","              ","       1,992","      ","           200","              "
                    ,"    34     ","     2,549,500","       7,684","        60,000","       1,200","              ","            ","     2,760,000","       6,884","       507,000","       2,136","       657,500","         134","129.68","           235","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","    17,570,200","      30,682","        60,000","       1,200","              ","            ","    17,780,700","      29,880","       507,000","       4,136","       657,500","       2,126","129.68","           435","              "
TUTE                ,"    41     ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
CRAPS               ,"    51     ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
TEXAS               ,"    61     ","              ","         200","              ","      15,400","              ","       7,984","              ","         200","              ","       8,500","              ","       1,084","      ","              ","              "
                    ,"    62     ","              ","         200","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","         200","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
                    ,"    63     ","              ","         200","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","         200","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","              ","         600","              ","      15,400","              ","       7,984","              ","         600","              ","       8,500","              ","       1,084","      ","              ","              "
PG                  ,"    71     ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
                    ,"    72     ","     2,725,300","       7,593","              ","            ","              ","            ","     2,667,800","       6,723","        50,000","         800","        -7,500","         -75","-15.00","            40","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","     2,725,300","       7,593","              ","            ","              ","            ","     2,667,800","       6,723","        50,000","         800","        -7,500","         -75","-15.00","            40","              "
MULTIJUEGOS         ,"    81     ","     5,491,000","      18,825","              ","            ","              ","            ","     5,491,000","      18,825","              ","            ","              ","            ","      ","              ","              "
                    ,"    82     ","     2,110,400","       5,314","              ","            ","              ","            ","     2,110,400","       5,174","              ","         180","              ","          40","      ","              ","              "
Subtotal            ,"           ","     7,601,400","      24,139","              ","            ","              ","            ","     7,601,400","      23,999","              ","         180","              ","          40","      ","              ","              "
```

Questions: 
- strings are enclosed between brackets and separated by string but number formatting also use a comma as thousand separator.
- I failed while using a split function ," being a potential separator
- tried to use several csv import scripts found on the web with no success.

Thanks in advance for your potential solutions!

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with some dummy data that is formatted exactly as your original data that needs to be split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
=split(substitute(A1,"""",";"),";,;",false)
```

This basically makes the values you actually want to split with unique - so it doesn't interfere with the commas in the number values - then uses that new delimiter as a splitter.